# Android: Is it possible to set parent of PopupWindow?

Tags: java, android, android-popupwindow

I displayed PopupWindow in fragment and it works well except when side menu appears. Side menu is displayed behind the PopupWindow which I don't want.

So I think it would be good to set parent of PopupWindow or maybe zOrder.

```
    LinearLayout contentView = (LinearLayout) inflate(getContext(), R.layout.callout_merge_destination, null);

    PopupWindow mCallout = new PopupWindow(contentView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    mCallout.showAsDropDown(view3, x, y);
```

Please let me know the best solution.